# upgrade from nunit 2.7.1 to nunit 3

Tags: c#, nunit

i'am upgrading my test project form nunit 2.7.1 to the actual version of nunit 3.
i have some question to the best practices of testrunner.
in the old project with nunit 2.7.1 i created the testrunner then chose the test class in the test package as follows:

```
//////some code before that
string testClass = "myTest";
TestPackage package;
ProcessModel processModel = ProcessModel.Default;
RuntimeFramework framework = RuntimeFramework.CurrentFramework;
string packageName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
package = new TestPackage(packageName);
// here i assigned the test to be done
package.TestName = testClass;
       
NUnit.Core.TestRunner testRunner = new 
InProcessTestRunnerFactory().MakeTestRunner(package);
testRunner.Load(package);
try{
   if (testRunner.Test == null)
    {
      testRunner.Unload();
      Console.Error.WriteLine("Unable to locate fixture {0}", testClass);
      return null;
    }

   MyEventListener collector = new MyEventListener();
   TestResult result = null;
   string savedDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
   try
   {
      result = testRunner.Run(collector, TestFilter.Empty, true, LoggingThreshold.Info);
   }
```

now in the nuunit 3 according to the documentation i can create testrunner like following:

```
// Get an interface to the engine
ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
// Create a simple test package - one assembly, no special settings
TestPackage package = new TestPackage("my.test.assembly.dll");
// Get a runner for the test package
ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);
// Run all the tests in the assembly
XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(listener: null, TestFilter.Empty);
```

how can i assign the "testclass" to the testrunner in nunit 3? only with a filter?
i want the testrunner only to run one testclass each time.

the second question is:
how to convert the testReuslt (from type XmlNode) to suitable datatype like TestResult in the namespace NUnit.Framework.Internal?